# Update existing IDs of changesets

Tags: liquibase

I have to update IDs in all changesets to follow the convention of naming. What is a correct sequence of doing that?

1. Update DATABASECHANGELOG table with new IDs
2. Update XML with changesets with new IDs
3. Clear checksums
4. Run liqibase

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sequence of

```
1. Update DATABASECHANGELOG table with new IDs
2. Update XML with changesets with new IDs
3. Clear checksums (or just set databasechangelog.MD5SUM = null)
4. Run liquibase
```

looks about right.

Or if your changeSets are simple enough, you can just update xml changeset IDs and make sure all of them will fail with preConditions.